# Numpy: mistake in getting indexing by numpy.argsort() in the array items after inverted it using sort() function

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, jupyter

peace be upon you guys,
When I invert the array items using the sort() function, Then I try to get the indexes,
First: that gives me the indexes of array items was before inverting.
Second: And if that's not wrong, why is there something wrong with indexes of some items.
example 1:

```py
in   x = np.random.randint(3,10,size=5) 
     x
out  array([8, 5, 3, 6, 6])
in   x.sort()
     x
out  array([3, 5, 6, 6, 8])
in   np.argsort(x)
out  array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4], dtype=int64)
in   x[::-1].sort()
     x
out  array([8, 6, 6, 5, 3])
in   np.argsort(x)
out  array([4, 3, 1, 2, 0], dtype=int64)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QUQBZ.png)
example 2:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4U08K.png)

Comment: I think it has something to do with how numpy handles array-slicing in conjunction with "sort" operating by side-effect.   Interestingly, you don't see the odd behavior if you use a list instead of a 1-d array.

Comment: It's not really clear to me what you are asking or what you were expecting. You cannot "invert the array items using the sort() function" – `sort` *sorts* the items, it does not invert them. Why do you think there is "something wrong with indexes of some items"?

Comment: Note that in ``array([8, 6, 6, 5, 3])``, the items at index ``1`` *and ``2``* have the same value ``6``. Sorting may arrange them in either order.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure what you mean by your second question, it seems to work as intended.
**Refer to documentation:**
https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html

Returns **the indices** that would sort an array.

Thus, for your last example:

```
x = np.array([9,9,8,4,3])
np.argsort(x)
```

The smallest element in `x` is 3 where its index in `x` is 4, the second smallest element in `x` is 4 where its index in `x` is 3, and so on.

```
array([4,3,2,0,1])
```

I would have commented but I don't have the reputation to do so.